# How to apply if condition in jframe constructor

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame named MyFrame

In the constructor `MyFrame()` I have an if condition

```
MyFrame() {

if(condition) {

openFrame();
}

}
```

If the condition in not true, I don't want to open the frame. Still it opens a blank frame.

Comment: Can you check it before calling the constructor?

Comment: `public class MyFrame {

MyFrame() {

if(condition) {
 init();
} else {
 // display msg
 return;
}

}

init() {
 // adding all components and displaying the frame
}


}
`


the above code displays the msg if the condition is false but at the same time opens a very small blank frame

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not checking `condition` until you're already in the process of creating your new `MyFrame`. If the condition is false, you skip `openFrame()`, which presumably adds content, but the `MyFrame` is still there. You should probably put the `if` statement around whatever is calling `new MyFrame()`.

Comment: `public class MyFrame {

MyFrame() {

if(condition) {
 init();
} else {
 // display msg
 return;
}

}

init() {
 // adding all components and displaying the frame
}


}
`


the above code displays the msg if the condition is false but at the same time opens a very small blank frame

Comment: Right, because the `MyFrame` instance (the blank frame) already exists. Check your `condition` *before* calling `new MyFrame()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid the conditions on `constructor`.

Most preferable way is

```
if (condition)  {

MyFrame  frame = new MyFrame();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `JFrame` in `if` condition rather than checking the condition after initializing.It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need this conditional check OUTSIDE the contructor. If that condition is met you do not want to have a Frame so don't bother creating one in the first place.

Comment: how do i check the condition outside constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

because somewhere you called the setVisible(true) to the MyFrame object, that is the only method call that makes a frame show.